# How can i load the main page without ruining the structure of requests

Tags: express

So, when the user gets on my website this script works in order to load the main page.

```
    router.use("/", async(req,res,next)=>{
    getMovies().then(movie=>{res.render("../view/index", {"movies": movie})})
})
```

But i guess this is not the right way to render the main page, because when i try to make a fetch request.

```
fetch('/otp-sent', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({status: "active"})
    })
```

It is not catched by my backend code.

```
router.post("/otp-sent", async(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
})
```

However, when i delete the first sequence of code, everything works as intended. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

[`router.use("/", ...)`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.use) handles all requests whose paths *start* with `/`, that is, all requests. Therefore your other middleware never gets a chance.

Use [`router.get("/", ...)`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD) instead, this handles only requests where the path *equals* `/`.

Comment: Amazing, so basic, and i couldn't figure it out. Thank you